# AlertDialog in seperate class to use in entire project

Tags: java, android-studio, android-alertdialog

I tried to use a seperate class in which Alertdialog is called for showing message. But app crashes without any error

```
package com.example.library;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class java_class {

    public void msgbox(Context context, String msg)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(context.getApplicationContext());
        dlgAlert.setMessage(msg)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                            {
                                //Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                // no action
                            }
                        })
                .show();
    }
}
```

in MainActivity i called it this way..

```
        Context context= getApplicationContext();
        java_class msbox=new java_class();
        msbox.msgbox(context,"Test");
```

when used debugger it ran upto 'public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)' line were app crashed.

but when i used the msgbox(String msg) in Mainactivity as function it works fine.

pls help...

Comment: Did you try to run the app from Android studio in debug mode (should be default option).  Is so, it's very unlikely it would crash the app without writing anything in Logcat. Could there be filter applied to your logcat ?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to ask app context from context.

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;


public class JavaClass {

    public void msgbox(Context context, String msg)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert  = new AlertDialog.Builder(context); //<- this changed 
        dlgAlert.setMessage(msg)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                            {
                                //Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                // no action
                            }
                        })
                .show();
    }
}
```

also you can use `this` to get context in activity class.

```
JavaClass javaClass = new JavaClass();
javaClass.msgbox(this, "Hello World2");
```

In Android, we can use the `this` keyword to get the context of the current Activity instance. When used inside an Activity, this refers to that Activity instance, which is a subclass of the Context class. If used inside a listener, we can reference the current context by using the Activity name, such as MainActivity.this in Java or this@MainActivity in Kotlin.

[image]

Comment: No sir... still I am getting the same error...

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: What do you mean by the next answer? There's a just my answer for now.  If you want to show image and stackOverflow doesn't allow it, just post it somewhere like imgur and include a link.